# BackboneJs destroy()

Tags: backbone.js, slim, destroy, notorm

I have this simple BackboneJs App. I am using Slim Framework and NotORM.
My problem is that, when I add new "task" (View), elements are added to DOM,and data is added to Database. But, immediately after adding View when I want to click remove (izbrisi) it removes it from DOM but not from Database. (NO DELETE REQUEST is SEND). After refreshing page, and clicking on delete button (izbrisi) everything works.

```
   (function(){

    window.App = {
      Models:{},
      Collections: {},
      Views : {}
    }

    window.template = function(id) {
    return _.template( jQuery('#' + id).html());
    }


     App.Models.Parti = Backbone.Model.extend({

               defaults: {


               },

               initialize:function()
               {

               },

               urlRoot: 'http://localhost/BackboneJS/vjezba6/server/index.php/task'

     });

     App.Collections.Partiji = Backbone.Collection.extend({

         model: App.Models.Parti,
         url: 'http://localhost/BackboneJS/vjezba6/server/index.php/task',

     });

     App.Views.Parti = Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName :"div",
        className: "box shadow aktivan",

        template: template("boxovi"),

        initialize: function() {
        //this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
        this.model.on('destroy', this.ukloni, this);


        },

        events: {
        'click #izbrisi': 'izbrisiItem',
        },

        izbrisiItem: function()
        {
          this.model.destroy();

        },

        ukloni:function()
        {
          this.$el.remove();
          console.log("frag");

        },

        render: function() {
            var template = this.template( this.model.toJSON() );

            this.$el.html(template);

            return this;
        }   
    });

     App.Views.Partiji = Backbone.View.extend({

         tagName:"div",
         id: "nosac-boxova",

        initialize: function() {
            this.collection.on('add', this.dodajPartyView, this);

            },

        render: function() {
        this.collection.each(this.dodajPartyView, this);

        return this;
        },

        dodajPartyView: function(party) {
        var partyView = new App.Views.Parti({ model: party });

        this.$el.append(partyView.render().el);
        }

    });

     App.Views.Dodaj =  Backbone.View.extend({

        tagName: "div",
        id: "dodajParty",
        template: template("dodajTemp"),
        events:{
           "submit": "submit"
        },

        submit: function(e)
        { 
               e.preventDefault();

               var inpNaziv =  $(e.currentTarget).find('.naziv').val();
               //var inpLokal =  $(e.currentTarget).find('.lokal').val();
               //var inpDatum =  $(e.currentTarget).find('.datum').val();
               var inpOpis =  $(e.currentTarget).find('.opis').val();



               var party = new App.Models.Parti
               ({
                    naziv: inpNaziv,
                    //lokal : inpLokal,
                    //datum : inpDatum,
                    tekst: inpOpis   

               });

              // this.collection.add(party);
               this.collection.create(party);


        },

        render: function() {
        var template = this.template();

        this.$el.html(template);

        return this;
        }   



    });



var kolekcijaPartija = new App.Collections.Partiji;
kolekcijaPartija.fetch();

var dodajView = new App.Views.Dodaj({collection:kolekcijaPartija});
$("div#sidebar-right").prepend(dodajView.render().el);

var partijiView = new App.Views.Partiji({collection: kolekcijaPartija});
$("div#content").prepend(partijiView.render().el);

})();
```

**EDIT 1**

```
App.Views.Partiji = Backbone.View.extend({

         tagName:"div",
         id: "nosac-boxova",

        initialize: function() {

            //this.collection.on('add', this.dodajParty, this);
            //this.collection.on('reset', this.dodajPartyView, this);

            },

        render: function() {
        //this.collection.each(this.dodajParty, this);
          console.log(this.collection.length);

        //return this;
        },

        dodajParty: function(party) {
            var partyView = new App.Views.Parti({ model: party });

            this.$el.append(partyView.render().el);

        }


    });
```

**RETURNS 0**

Comment: hm...how many #izbrisi element do you have on the page? ID has to be unique in the DOM.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. in your prepend() methods, use view.render().$el.html() instead of just .el and try again.

Comment: No, thats not solution, but thank's for your help

Comment: Where are the events for the delete link?

Comment: It sounds like your not returning an `id` attribute to your model from the server when you initially add the model. If you don't have an `id` attribute when you invoke `destroy` on a model, Backbone doesn't even bother sending a `DELETE` request to the server.

Comment: How can i acommplish that @fbynite ?

Comment: @fbynite is correct you need an id otherwise Backbone does not know how to build the url, you can set a different field by using `idAttribute:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this:

```
this.model.on('destroy', this.ukloni, this);
```

With This:

```
this.model.on('remove', this.ukloni, this);
```

Your 'events' removes it from DOM, when Backbone detect that event it will run ur function 'ukloni'